# Xposed findClass() returning java.lang.Class

Tags: java, xposed

I am trying to hook a method inside the Always-On Display code for OnePlus phones, but when I use XposedHelpers.findClass() it ends up returning java.lang.Class, and as such returns a noSuchMethodError.

Call code:

```js
findAndHookMethod("com.oneplus.aod.OpAodThreeKeyStatusView", lpparam.classLoader, "onThreeKeyChanged", "int", new XC_MethodHook() {
  @Override
  protected void afterHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param) throws Throwable {
  XposedHelpers.callMethod((XposedHelpers.findClass("com.oneplus.aod.OpAodDisplayViewManager", lpparam.classLoader)), "startDozing");
  }
});
```

I'm trying to call "com.oneplus.aod.OpAodDisplayViewManager" which I know exists because I extracted the APK from my own phone. However, it returns java.lang.Class and then returns that the method "startDozing" doesn't exist.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. The `findClass()` method returns a `java.lang.Class` object by design.

Comment: @Progman in that case, how do I call a method in a class after I hook a different class? Usually when I encounter the "noSuchMethodError" it lists the class and method that I called, e.g. "com.example#method()#bestmatch" but in this case it returns an error with "java.lang.Class#method()#bestmatch"

Comment: Is `startDozing()` a static method or non-static method?

Comment: @Progman it's non-static, it's "public void startDozing()"

Comment: Then you use `XposedHelpers.callMethod()`, but you need an object of the type `com.oneplus.aod.OpAodDisplayViewManager` to call this method on, not a `java.lang.Class` object. You have to check where you get the `OpAodDisplayViewManager` object from.

Comment: @Progman sorry I'm fairly new to Xposed and Java and I'm not sure I follow. How would I get an object of the type "com.oneplus.aod.OpAodDisplayViewManager"? I understand that is the class, I don't know how that can be made into an object

Comment: What you need is a method that gets an `OpAodDisplayViewManager` object as parameter or an object that has a field that holds an `OpAodDisplayViewManager`. You should check the code for each and every variable/field that holds an `OpAodDisplayViewManager` and check if you can manage to access it by a method or field.

Comment: @Robert thanks for the response, I found that simply creating an Object variable at the beginning solved the problem of grabbing an object! `Object displayManager = "com.oneplus.aod.OpAodDisplayViewManager"`

Comment: Please write an full answer with you now working code and a description, not just mark the question in the title. Stackoverflow is not a a forum.

Comment: @Robert apologies, I have now done so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since XposedHelpers.findClass() returns java.lang.Class, the solution was to instantiate a new Object like so:

```java
Object displayManager = "com.oneplus.aod.OpAodDisplayViewManager"
```

and then call the method using that object rather than the findClass() function

Comment: This line of code is still not a valid answer as the context how this variable is used is unclear. Why don't you just copy the whole code block into your answer?